# Why is force due to surface tension neglected here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, surface-tension

I was solving question 2.07 from MIT's advanced FM and it was asked to find the force required to hold to glass plates in place when water is placed between them.

I solved by showing that due to the lower pressure in the region inside the squeezed droplet, the plates are squeezed inwards. So I found the force of the squeeze.

This was also how they solved it, but on looking at the solution and the diagrams I wondered why would surface tension not provide an "extra" force?

I will give any further clarifications if required.

Hope my question was understandable, I will link the [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-25-advanced-fluid-mechanics-fall-2013/surface-tension-and-its-importance/MIT2_25F13_Solution2.07.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean "why is there no force propertional to the *perimeter* of the water droplet in addition to the force proprotional to the *area* from the pressure difference."

I think that there are two things to consider: 1) The  wetting condition means that the surface tension at the edge is pulling inwards and has no vertical component; 2)  If the droplet is circular of  radius $\rho$ then the pressure difference formula is not just $+\sigma/R$ but also has a contribution  $-\sigma/\rho$. I think that this is being neglected becuse   $\rho\gg R$.

Comment: Yes sir that is what I mean sorry for my bad articulation, but it is given that the contact angle is alpha therefore a component exists

Comment: Yes. I misread the problem. There will be a perimeter contribution then. I guess that they are just ignoring it.  This is the usual issue with any exam/homework  problem: in addition to knowing the physics, you have a make a model of what is in  the question-creator's mind. This is often harder than the physics.